# How do I use the TEXT function to delete the comma from my Calculated formula for the Fiscal Year?

Tags: calculated-column

I'm working in SharePoint 2013.

I created a calculated column of data type = SLOT with the formula:

```
=IF(Month(Created)>9,Year(Created)+1,Year(Created))
```

It works but it's returning the as 2,019 (with a comma).

I tried wrapping the TEXT function around the above formula as follows:

```
=TEXT((IF(Month(Created)>9,Year(Created)+1,Year(Created))),"YY")
```

but this returns "05"

I don't have access to Notepad++.  I tried to troubleshoot in Excel but with no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "`The data type returned from this formula is:`" to Single line of text and change the formula to this:

```
=TEXT(IF(MONTH(Created)>9,YEAR(Created)+1,YEAR(Created)), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As to why your formula returned 05...

```
=TEXT((IF(Month(Created)>9,Year(Created)+1,Year(Created))),"YY")
```

1. YEAR(*somedate*) returns something like 2019.
2. TEXT(2019, "YY")  returns the year for the 2019th day from 12/31/1899, which is in the year 1905. ( 7/11/1905 ) The "YY" then returns the "05" of the "1905". TEXT needs a DATE not just a number.

Two possible solutions:

- Not using the TEXT function:

  `="" & IF( MONTH(Created)>9, YEAR(Created)+1, YEAR(Created) )`    the quotes force the result to text.

  or

  `=RIGHT( IF( MONTH(created)>9, YEAR(created)+1, YEAR(created)), 2 )`   to only return a two digit year.
- Using the TEXT function in case you are doing other TEXT formatting: (it needs a DATE not just a year number)

  `=TEXT( IF( MONTH(created)>9, DATE(YEAR(created)+1,1,1), DATE(YEAR(created),1,1)), "YY")`

  a shortened version:

  `=TEXT( DATE(YEAR(created) + IF(MONTH(created)>9,1,0),1,1), "YY")`